# Bad request when client call a webservice that also calls another webservice

Tags: vb.net, web-services, .net-2.0

I have a client application that calls a function1 on webservice1 on server1 in the local network. The webservice1 then calls another webservice2 on an remote server2.

If open Internet Explorer on server1 and point it to the function1 on webservice1 and run the function, everything goes fine.

But if I run it from the client computer I got "bad request", "protocolerror". All other webservice functions works fine from the client, only the function that itself call another function on another server got this error.

Is there any security context I must handle that I dont know about or anything else you can guess from what I described?

Client is winXP and win2003, server1 is a virtual 2003 server on a physical win2008 server.

Google could not help me here, I could se other with same problems but no solution.

When Im running in my developement setup (webservice1 and client on my computer, there are no problem)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the anonymous access account (IUSR_blahblahblah) for your first web service is a member of a network group that has access to the second web server.